# How can I configure WebStorm to stop importing the full Typescript paths?

Tags: angular, typescript, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Recently there was an upgrade in WebStorm (I think) and it changed how paths were imported in my files. Previously, if I typed `@Component` and allow WebStorm to automatically import the path, it would use this form:

```
import { Component } from @angular/core
```

But recently it has started pulling in the full paths instead:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core/src/metadata/directives';
```

Is there a configuration change I can make to address this?

[EDIT]
I discovered that if I copy and paste code into a file, it will import the dependencies properly. This feels like a bug that my particular configuration is revealing.

It appears that the *only* libraries that do this are Angular libraries, so I suspect the problem is with the Angular plugin. I have reached out to JetBrains and they have no answers.

Comment: Try selecting "Invalidate caches / Reset" from the file menu and clear your caches.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I selected "Invalidate caches / Restart" and it didn't make a difference; I still get the whole path.

Comment: I have seen this happen to me for my own libraries when I use `ng generate library`. I follow the documentation guide, but WebStorm keeps importing the long form of the path for the library components. I'm wondering if this is a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And like that, one day, I log back in to discover the bug has been fixed. This appears to have been a problem with the Angular Plugin as imports for other libraries worked properly. Things that I tried to fix this include:

- Restart Webstorm/Whole OS (I come from the Windows world)
- File > Invalidate Caches / Restart...
- Nearly every configuration of import options.
- Fix a broken Webpack.config (give a default entry point)
- Reinstall the Angular Plugin
- Delete all WebStorm Configuration, restart and rebuild configuration by hand.
- File a bug report with JetBrains which resulted in the support staff saying "I don't know"

None of the above did anything. I would love if someone from JetBrains would help me understand how to better help them understand bugs I find.

This isn't exactly a fix for the bug, but if anyone else discovers this happening in their code, hopefully, this will help them debug.